# Javascript Google Maps API & non-passive event handlers

Tags: addeventlistener, passive-event-listeners

Recently Chrome started emitting the following warnings:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

These are coming from the JavaScript Google Maps API code.  I'm able to add {passive: true} to addEventListener() in my own code but don't know how to suppress the warning in Googles libraries?

Comment: So you are saying that Chrome wasn't showing these messages before? So you think that an update changed things? Or do you think an update to the Maps API changed?

Comment: Hello, Did you fix this? I am facing same issue. Thx

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and it is really weird that the google maps api doesn't integrate the passive property. Any solution?

Comment: I am facing same issue. It is surprising to me that this question hasn't been answered yet. Any solution from anyone?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me. Got here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55388961/2233069

```
(function () {
    if (typeof EventTarget !== "undefined") {
        let func = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
        EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function (type, fn, capture) {
            this.func = func;
            if(typeof capture !== "boolean"){
                capture = capture || {};
                capture.passive = false;
            }
            this.func(type, fn, capture);
        };
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do at this point. It's a warning that is generated from Googles own API code. As long as your own event listeners are passive, I think it can be safely ignored.

Comment: You will also notice that none of the examples shown in Googles own Maps API documentation for event listeners are using passive event listeners.