# Google Map embedded iframe

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I am using the embedded google map inside of an iframe in my vue js application.  It was working fine up until recently.  In the last month or so I have started getting warning messages in the console regarding the touchstart event listeners.  I have read that this is an improvement in one of chrome's updates.  Is there anyway to get rid of these warnings?  Or can that only be resolved by Google?

Thank you for the help.

Below is a screenshot of the warnings.

[image]

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799388/javascript-google-maps-api-non-passive-event-handlers. Basically Chrome is complaining because built-in event listeners of google-maps-api are inneficiently forcing a reflow. Go figure...

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.